# How to create a hyperlink using the id of an item in a client template on Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

So I have a Kendo Grid using the 'Hierarchical' mechanism. When I come to my Client Template portion, I'm doing this:

```
 .Columns(column =>
                    {
                        column.Bound(o => o.Id).Width(110);
                        column.Bound(o => o.Title);
                        column.Bound(model => model.Id)
                                    .ClientTemplate(String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" data-title=\"View Stuff\" class=\"stuff\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyph-btn directory\">Stuff</i></a>", Url.Action("Details", "Stuff", new { Id = "#=Id#" })))
                                    .Width(40)
                                    .Title("View");                    
                    })
```

When I run this up, the Id (on the first column) is coming out correctly - identifying the group item by its correct Id. However, when I try to use "#=Id#" in my hyperlink, this always refers to the Id of the original item that I clicked to show the group (client template).

Does anyone know how to use the Id of the group item (i.e. the output of that first column) in the hyperlink?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the answer to this [telerik question](http://www.telerik.com/forums/column-clienttemplate-in-clientdetailtemplate):

You need to use `\\#Id\\#` within your `ChildTemplate` method to indicate you are accessing the current child element, not the parent. Change your syntax to the following:

```
.ClientTemplate(String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" data-title=\"View Stuff\" class=\"stuff\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyph-btn directory\">Stuff</i></a>", Url.Action("Details", "Stuff", new { Id = "\\#=Id\\#" })))
```